# How to prevent pushing "stupid test code" to master with Unit Tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Currently my app does not have any type of Test Driven Development or Behaviour Driven Development. I didn't prioritise beforehand and I would like to get some information about where to go from here.

My app is currently a:

- Ruby
- Rails
- `html.erb` views
- PSQL

For now, the primary concern is the front end of things. For example, when I am building up views, I will add things like

```
.some_div_container { 
  background: red;
  border 1px dashed green;
}
```

but I will forget to take it out. I guess I can specifically test to make sure a div does not have a red background, but... what if I do something like orange, blue, etc...

Also for things like debuggers, binding.prys and console.log. Is there a test case for when I have something like

```
<button type="button" onclick="doStuff">Kanye West</button>

function doStuff() {
  console.log("I am the number one most impactful artist of our generation!")
}
```

I guess you can kind of get the idea of how stupid this can look when it's on master, and what I can do prevent this and/or how I can go about Unit Testing.

Comment: So is your question how you can go about frontend testing in rails? Which version of rails are you running?

Comment: @Niklas Rails 4.0.3. And yes, it's mainly with front end things, where I add stupid stylings, classes and whatnot .